# Trying to for loop MeCab to analyze text descriptions in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, while-loop, mecab

*（Update）As I noted in the comment, somehow I got to run the code successfully but still it is taking way too long like 30 minutes. I would really appreciate if you all could help me figure out more efficient way to compose the code.*

I am trying to run the code to analyze the description column in a dataframe but everytime I run it I get runt timeout error. Probably because the dataframe has more than 200,000 rows and the code below is not efficient. Could someone help me understand what is wrong with the code?

```
list = df["description"].tolist()
new_list = []

for li in list:
    tagger = MeCab.Tagger(ipadic.MECAB_ARGS)
    node = tagger.parseToNode(li)
    keywords = []
    while node:
        if node.feature.split(",")[2] == "組織": #組織 means organization
            keywords.append(node.surface)
        node = node.next
    new_list.append(keywords)
    
df["description"] = new_list
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message, plus the traceback, if possible? As an edit, not as a comment.

Comment: Sorry this time it worked and I didn't keep the exact error code. It still took very long time. Do you think you can help me make it more efficient? Really appreciate your response!

Comment: Your error message was probably about running out of memory and included a reference to "mmap" somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the Tagger outside the loop.

```
tagger = MeCab.Tagger(ipadic.MECAB_ARGS)
for li in list:
    ...
```

The Tagger has a startup cost. It's a small cost, but the object is designed to be reused and shouldn't be recreated inside a loop like that.

Please see [this post](https://www.dampfkraft.com/nlp/how-to-tokenize-japanese.html#the-tagger-object-has-a-startup-cost) about using MeCab in Python, which has a section specifically on this problem.

Comment: Wow! This is great. It only took 5 seconds! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad I could help. For helpful answers, you should upvote them, and then accept them by clicking the large check mark to the left.

Comment: Thanks for the note and sorry about that. I’m new here. Done!